# cannot find '@angular/http' in angular CLI version 7.1.0

Tags: angular

cannot cannot find '**@angular/http**' in angular CLI version 7.1.0., Also **http** not present in **package.json**

Comment: what do you mean by angular CLI version?

Comment: It's deprecated since version 4.3 of Angular. Why do you still want to use that? Use the documented HttpClient. https://angular.io/guide/http

Answer (score 2):

'@angular/http' is depricated and in version 7 is now removed from the generated package.json file,use HttpClient from '@angular/common/http'.

Import in app.module.ts

```
     import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';

     @NgModule({
        imports: [          
       // import HttpClientModule 
       HttpClientModule,
      ]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
npm install @angular/http@latest
```